# How do I replace a zip file in a forked repository

Tags: github

I need to update a zip file forked from another user's github repository.

I have a repository forked from https://github.com/k2zia/AD985XSPI that contains only two files, a readme, and a zip file (AD985XSPI.zip).  The zip file is an Arduino library that does not contain a "libraries.properties" file, a requirement that has been added since the time the original repository was created.  I downloaded the zip file, unzipped it, added a "libraries.properties" file, rezipped, and now need to replace the existing zip file in my repository.

I am unclear on how to accomplish this task.

Comment: What you're asking about is the very basics of git in general. It's unclear what *specifically* you're trying to do. Are you trying to merge this into the repository you've linked? Or are you trying to simply push to your own fork? Do you have git installed on your computer?

Comment: I am very new to git, so the basics is where I'm at.  What I want to accomplish is to have the modified zip file resident in my own repository, and to have no effect on the repository from which I have forked.  Does this mean I am "trying to simply push to [my] own fork?" I do not have git installed on my computer, I am using github.com as a means for organizing my coding work.

Comment: Hey, no worries. From the GitHub interface, you should be able to see an "Upload files" button next to the green clone button. Try using that button on your own fork of the repository. That should work for you :)

Comment: This goes beyond what you initially asked, but since you mentioned you're just learning git and GitHub, I'd like to add this:   Git excels at tracking changes to individual files (that's precisely what it was built to do!) -- so zipping up a whole folder sort of defeats the purpose of git. You should install git on your computer and run through a super-simple tutorial, like [this one](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/). Let me know what you think :)

Comment: First, thanks.  I believe I have accomplished my initial objective, using the "Upload files" button. I believe that my next objective will be to unzip and upload all the individual files to my repository.  Since the time I forked k2zia's repository, I have been unclear as to why he (she?) included only the zip file and readme, with none of the files that make up the content of the zip file.  I will follow your recommendations.  Thanks again.